# How to do this templating in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js

I've got an application template that houses an outlet in a section tag, and also includes some other tags like a header, footer etc. The outlet gets used when I root to, say, a `posts` route and it uses the `PostsController`. The page then gets filled out with the posts template. However when I navigate to the home route `/`, then the `#main` section is blank.

```
<header>My header</header>

<section id='main'>
  {{ outlet }}
</section>

<footer>My footer</footer>
```

I'd like to use that outlet to display something when I'm at the home route, but have that outlet filled with something else (like the posts template) when I navigate to posts. I've tried doing something like adding:

```
{{#if isRoot}}
  lorem ipsum
{{/if}}
```

and then adding this to the `applicationController`:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  isRoot: true
})
```

but even when I navigate to `posts` that remains true (as I understand it, because the other controllers are nested inside the application controller). What's an idiomatic way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index route was created for this exact problem.  It's used when you hit a endpoint and no deeper, allowing you to show something when you are just at that endpoint.

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  // you can return a different model, or just use the application's model
});


<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  I'm only at the root of my app!
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to use the script tags, I just use the handlebar curly braces but if I add `App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  isRoot: true
});` it still doesn't work.

Comment: So you want the non idiomatic way to do it your way instead of the ember way? You can watch currentPath property, it's only defined on the application controller. You could also use computed equal to simply set it up